# Disable sync for an entity with Simperium for iOS

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, simperium

I have an app with several `CoreData` entities. Most of them must be synced but I need a couple of them to be just used as local entities (no sync for them). I tried to avoid adding simperiumKey and ghostData to the entities and let them inherit from `NSManagedObject` instead of `SPManagedObjet`, but Simperium's framework crashes because it doesn't succeed to sync the entities. How can I disable sync for one or more entities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your initial approach was correct:

- Entities that need sync'ing require to inherit from `SPManagedObject
- Entities that don't need sync'ing can inherit directly from `NSManagedObject`

The framework *shouldn't* be crashing. Can you please post the crashlog so we can troubleshoot?

Please, feel free of opening an issue directly in our GitHub repository: http://github.com/Simperium/simperium-ios

Thank you!

Comment: Thank you Jeorge... I'm dumb, I didn't see that one of the objects that must not be synced was actually inheriting from SPManagedObject.... .. my mistake, I'm sorry. I wanted to delete the question but you were faster than me...

Comment: You're not dumb @Sergiob!!! Can definitely happen to anyone. Hope you have an awesome day!

Comment: Please, can you also answer to my last question on Simperium? Thank you